# Remove element at index from sequence

Tags: nim-lang

I have a `sequence` and I want to remove an element from it at a certain index. How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use delete:

```
var
  a = @[1, 2, 3]

echo a
a.delete(1)  
echo a
```

Link:
http://ideone.com/4IE3cI

```
@[1, 2, 3]
@[1, 3]
```